# Как формируется ударение в слове  просянОй от прОсо

Tags: фонетика

Как-то задавала здесь вопрос: как правильно  -  тЕльное или тельнОе. Получила очень хороший, аргументированный ответ. Приведу, ответ, чтобы было от чего оттолкнуться. " Поскольку в нашем случае мы имеем дело с обычным прилагательным тельное (не отглагольным и не кратким), то правильно будет сохранить ударение от слова-образователя (тЕло): тЕльное. Ударение тельнОе, безусловно, ярко выделяет принадлежность прилагательного к среднему роду, но это излишне - поскольку вариант тЕльное на слух отличается от тЕльная." 
 Очень хотелось бы получить  объяснение на  формирование  ударения в слове просянОй.

Answer (score 2):

http://rusgram.narod.ru/609-645.html  § 624. Прилагательные с суф. -ан-.
   В прилагательных, мотивированных словами с односложной основой, преобладает ударение на флексии, независимо от ударения мотивирующего слова: торф, -у -торфянОй; трава, -е, -ам - травянОй; кость, -и, -ям - костяной; тафта, -е - тафтяной.В нашем случае прос-о- - просянОй

При этом в прилагательных, мотивированных словами акц. типа А, ударение иногда на основе (кожа - кожаный, глина - глиняный, нить - нитяный), а в мотивированных словами других акц. типов - на суффиксе (мёд, -у, -ам - медвяный; песок, -у - песчаный), либо вариантное на суффиксе и флексии (роса, -е, -ам - росяный и росяной; овёс, -у - овсяный и овсяной). Исключение: масло, -у, -ам - масляный. В немногих прилагательных, мотивированных словами с неодносложной основой, ударение чаще на суффиксе: таволжаный, очеретяный, конопляный (но селитряный, финифтяный, серебряный с ударением на основе; берестяной, хворостяной, волосяной - на флексии).

Comment: Спасибо большое, все понятно!

Comment: тогда примите ответ (слева под ладошкой кружочек с галочкой)

Comment: К сожалению, не могу, у меня недостаточно очков))

Comment: В словаре Резниченко (наверное, и в других словарях) даются развернутые комментарии, поясняющие выбор ударения, при этом они  очень похожи на наблюдения и обобщение этих наблюдений, учитывая, что правил бывает больше, чем исключений. А какие реальные факторы влияют на выбор ударения, например, в слове "просяной"? Мне кажется, это могут быть два фактора: фонетический и смысловой, причем изучить этот вопрос можно сравнивая парные варианты, например: врЕменный - временнОй, домОвый и домовОй, переходный - переходной.  Интересно, есть ли какие исследования по этой теме?